# yii active record related records from another databases

Tags: php, yii

I have model named SuperModel in one module/models folder. And related ChildModel1, ChildModel2 in another module/models folder.

SuperModel data record from database1 must contain related records Child1 and Child2, which placed in another databases.

Is there way to get record using relations from few databases at the same time via yii ActiveRecord relationship mechanism? Something like that:

```
$super_record = SuperRecordModel::model()->with( 
    'RecordFromDB_A',
    'RecordFromDB_B' 
)->findAll( $criteria );
```

Or I need use something like:

```
// From first DB...
$super_record = SuperRecordModel::model()->findAll();

// Separately from another DB A...
$super_record->ChildsA = ChildsAModel::model()->findAll(
    't.parent_id = :super_record_id'
);

// Separately from another DB B...
$super_record->ChildsB = ChildsBModel::model()->findAll( 
    't.parent_id = :super_record_id'
);
```

How is right?

UPDATE: I can't use yii active record relationship in multi-database select actions... How can I switch between databases within active record method? Example:

```
$catalogs = $this->findAll();

// Set new database connection for this context..
// $this->setDbConnection( yii::app()->db2 );

foreach( $catalogs as &$catalog ) {
    $catalog->service = Services::model()->find(
        't.catalog_id = :catalog_id', ... );
    // this gives error: table services cannot be found in the database
}
```

Comment: Have you tested either approach to see if it works? I don't have a yii setup to test on. I found this about mutliple database support in yii.... http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/

Comment: Thanks @joshjwalker , I've read this doc and now understand what I need to realize second variant of code... How can I switch between databases within active record method?

Comment: In your "Services" ActiveRecord model, you need to define your alternate database connection similar to the section "GetDbConnection() override" of the article I sent. That would be my best guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I explored documentation, comments and now this problem is solved.

> Tables in one database cannot directly reference tables in another
>   database, and this means that relations don't cross DB boundaries.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/

Solution. Lets write setup params for all db connections which module will be use in the future. Example:

```
'modules' => array(
    'module_name' => array(
        'db1' => array(
            'class' => 'CDbConnection',
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=...;dbname=db1',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'password',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
        'db2' => array(
            'class' => 'CDbConnection',
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=...;dbname=db2',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'password',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
    )
),

...
```

In module init() method or another logic entry point you need to create objects of CDbConnection class, it's something like that:

```
$db1_connection = Yii::createComponent( Yii::app()->controller->module->db1 );
$db2_connection = Yii::createComponent( Yii::app()->controller->module->db2 );
```

Then use [`CDbConnection::createCommand`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#createCommand-detail) to get needed data from databases.

```
// Records from db1.
$parent_records = $db1_connection
    ->createCommand('SELECT * FROM parent_table')
    ->queryAll();

// Records from db2 as childs of parent record.
foreach( $parent_records as &$parent_record ) {
    $parent_record['childs'] = $db2_connection
        ->createCommand('SELECT * FROM child_table WHERE parent_id = :parent_id')
        ->bindParam(':parent_id', $parent_record['parent_id'])
        ->queryAll();
}
```

Comment: Please note that relations between tables in different databases are supported in Yii 2.0.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#cross-database-relations